# AS3 iterating through class variables

Tags: actionscript-3

how can i iterate through all the variables of a class instance?
it appears to work for regular objects...

Edited: This will do it =)

```
var test:anyClass=new anyClass();
var someObject:Object={val1:"object string",val2:111,val3:new Date()};
var xmlList:XMLList=describeType(anyClass)..variable;
for each(var key:* in someObject)
    trace(String(key));
for each(var item:XML in xmlList)
    trace(String(test[item.@name]));
```

output:
object string
111
Thu Nov 8 11:19:27 GMT-0700 2012
class string
222
Thu Nov 8 11:19:27 GMT-0700 2012

```
public class anyClass
{
    public var val1:String="class string";
    public var val2:int=222;
    public var val3:Date=new Date();
}
```

Comment: Take a look of this properties in the Object class http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#propertyIsEnumerable() and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#setPropertyIsEnumerable()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use `flash.utils.describeType()`

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()

This returns an XML document describing all the details of a class, which you can then attack with normal E4X. Here's an example which I've tested:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.describeType;

var test:String = "TEST";

function DescribeTypeExample():void {
    var child:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var description:XML = describeType(this);
    var variables:XMLList = description..variable;
    for each(var variable:XML in variables) {
        trace("VARIABLE: " + variable.@name);
        trace("VALUE: " + this[variable.@name]);
    }
}

this.DescribeTypeExample();

// Output:

// VARIABLE: test
// VALUE: TEST
```

Comment: Oh, nice, i already saw that but i though, "maybe this inst really necessary". Turns out i was wrong...
And im using it on items from a bindable ArrayCollection, so accessor does it for me.

Comment: I realised a plain Sprite doesn't have any variables (D'oh!) so changed to another example, which I've tested. If accessors work for you then great.

Comment: hey guys i am not able to retrieve vars of a class that is not dynamic is there any way to do that ?

Comment: @freezing_ You're more likely to get an answer if you post a question than a comment. Show what you're trying to do, and why it doesn't work, with some sample code - someone will then surely be able to help.